# Strings won't concatenate correctly in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, string-concatenation, feof

I have a loop running in a PHP script that's part of a .inc.php (it's a header that reads from a .txt file so that it can add to it's navbar from information solely from the .txt). For example, in the .txt could be:

> about
>
> contact
>
> support

It reads the text file in a line by line basis and returns each line as  a string, which is then echoed out as a link in the navbar. For whatever reason, the about and contact links don't have the ".php" extension, but the support link does. No matter what's put into the .txt file, the last line of it will always get the extension, while the others don't. I've juggled around quotations within the echo statement, but to no avail. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

```
<?php

    if (file_exists("pagespage.txt")) {

       $newFile = fopen('pagespage.txt', 'r');

       while (! feof($newFile)) {
           $pagename = fgets($newFile);
           $pagenamecap = ucwords($pagename);
           echo "<li><a class=button href=" . "$pagename.php>" . $pagenamecap . "</a></li>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the file looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<li><a class=button href=contact
.php>Contact
</a></li>
```

Can you see why this might be a problem?

Firstly, add quotes around your attributes. Second, `trim` your string.

```
$pagename = trim(fgets($newFile));
$pagenamecap = ucfirst($pagename);
echo '<li><a class="button" href="'.$pagename.'.php">'.$pagenamecap.'</a></li>';
```

("Support" didn't have this problem because it was the last line in the file, and therefore didn't have a newline at the end of it)

Answer (score 2):

Your link structure is incorrect. You need quotes around the href. You don't need to come out of the echo to concatenate.

```
echo "<li><a class=button href='$pagename.php'>$pagenamecap </a></li>";
```

You can use braces `{}` around the variable names to make sure it doesn't get mixed with any other word:

```
echo "<li><a class=button href='{$pagename}.php'>{$pagenamecap} </a></li>";
```

Comment: Quotes are technically optional around attribute values, provided they are limited in what symbols they contain.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I guess it's so ingrained in my head. It doesn't look right to me, and it's probably better practice to use them.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. No denying that. But this won't fix the problem, because the `href` will be `contact%0D%0A.php`, which will doubtless lead to a 404 :)